# How to parse a string from fgets to be stored in argv[] for a simple command line interpreter?

Tags: c, shell, parsing, fgets

I am attempting to create a simple shell program, and take input from the user using fgets(). I store the user input in a char[], and then attempt to parse it using a getword() method I wrote. However, I cannot figure out how to get the getword() method to parse the string. I can print out the commandLine char[] and see exactly what is typed at the prompt, but it does no get parsed. getword() returns the same string unparsed , and tries to store the whole thing in argv[0]. I have tested the getword() method alone and it returns what I want it to. Here is my current attempt:

**The main shell program:**

```
int main() {
    pid_t pid, first, second;
    mode_t fileBits;
    size_t ln;
    int argc, inputRedirect, firstStatus, i, execvpReturnVal;
    int childOutput_fd;
    long octalPermissionString;
    char *home = getenv("HOME");
    char *argv[MAXITEM];
    char devNull[10] = "/dev/null";
    char commandLine[STORAGE];
    struct stat fileStats;

    signal(SIGTERM, myhandler);

    for (;;) {
        background = 0;
        printf("p2: ");
        fflush(stdout);


        /*---------FGETS PROMPT----------*/

        fgets(commandLine, STORAGE, stdin);
        commandLine[strlen(commandLine) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("commandLine = [%s]\n", commandLine);
/*==============OTHER SHELL METHODS=============*/
```

**parse() method that calls getword():**

```
int parse(char *commandLine, char *argv[]) {
    int argc = 0;
     char *commandPointer;
     argv[argc++] = commandLine;
     printf("argv[%d] = [%s]\n", argc-1, commandLine);

     do{
     commandPointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STORAGE);
     argv[argc++] = commandPointer;
     printf("argv[%d] = [%s]\n", argc-1, commandPointer);
     getword(commandPointer);
     }while(*commandPointer != '\0');
     argc--;
     argv[argc] = '\0';
     return argc;

}
```

**getword() parse method:**

```
/*Function Prototypes*/
int tilde(char *p, int i);
int isMeta(int thisChar);


int getword(char *w) {

int currChar, nextChar, offset;
int index = 0;
int *tildeHelper;

currChar = getchar();

while(currChar == ' ' || currChar == '\t') {
    currChar = getchar();
}

if(currChar == EOF)
    return -1;


switch(currChar) {
    case '\0':
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '\n':
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case ';':
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '<':
        w[index++] = currChar;
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '>':
        w[index++] = currChar;
        if((nextChar = getchar()) == '>')
            w[index++] = currChar;
        else {
            ungetc(nextChar, stdin);
        }
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '|':
        w[index++] = currChar;
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '&':
        w[index++] = currChar;
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
    case '~':
        tildeHelper = &index;
        index = tilde(&w[index], *tildeHelper);

    default:
        w[index++] = currChar;
        while((currChar = getchar()) != ' ' && currChar != '<' && currChar != '>' && currChar != '|' && currChar != ';' && currChar != '&' && currChar != '\t' && currChar != '\n' && currChar != '\0' && currChar != EOF && index <= STORAGE - 1) {
            switch(currChar) {
                case '~':
                    tildeHelper = &index;
                    index = tilde(&w[index], *tildeHelper);
                    break;

                case '\\':
                    nextChar = getchar();
                    if(metaCharacter(nextChar))
                        w[index++] = nextChar;
                    else {
                        ungetc(nextChar, stdin);
                        w[index++] = currChar;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    w[index++] = currChar;
            }
        }
        ungetc(currChar, stdin);
        w[index] = '\0';
        return index;
}
}


int tilde(char *cp, int i) {
    int *ip = &i;
    char *p = cp;
    char *o;
    o = (strcpy(p, getenv("HOME")));
    int offset = strlen(o);
    *ip = *ip + offset;
    return i;
}

int metaCharacter(int thisChar) {
    int isMeta = 0;
    switch(thisChar) {
        case '~':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case '<':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case '>':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case '|':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case ';':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case '&':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
        case '\\':
            isMeta = 1;
            break;
    }
    return isMeta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read the command line from `stdin` twice. First, you read the whole line with `fgets()`, then, in `getword` you try to get the next character with `getchar()`. This tries, in effect, to read a second line. You should read the char buffer that contains the line instead.

Update your `getword` function to take a second argument `src`, the line to read. Then replace all calls to `getline` with `*src++`:

```
int getword(char *w, const char *src) {

    int currChar, nextChar, offset;
    int index = 0;
    int *tildeHelper;

    currChar = *src++;
    while(currChar == ' ' || currChar == '\t') currChar = *src++;

    /* ... */
}
```

Your `parse` function must then pass the command line to `getword` and use the return value from `getword` to update the string position:

```
int parse(char *commandLine, char *argv[])
{
    int argc = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (1) {
        char *commandPointer = malloc(sizeof(char) * STORAGE);
        index += getword(commandPointer, commandLine + index);
        if (*commandPointer == '\0') break;
        argv[argc++] = commandPointer;
    } 

    return argc;
}
```

You then still have issues in the code, for example not getting the return value of `getword` right and not freeing the argument strings.

Also, for implementing a shell, have a look at `getline`, which is a better command-line input interface than plain old `fgets´.